# In table vertical alignment of text

Tags: tables, margins

Question: In my table I found that text is not vertical aligned.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
a4paper,top=0.7in,bottom=0.4in,left=0.7in,right=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\headsep=10pt
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline\rule[-1.2ex]{00pt}{5ex}
    Class & $(f_i)$ &  $(x_i)$ & $f_i \cdot x_i$      \\ \hline
    $0 - 2$          & $1$                      & $1$                & $1$                  \\ \hline
    $2 - 4$          & $2$                      & $3$                & $6$                  \\ \hline
    $4 - 6$          & $1$                      & $5$                & $5$                  \\ \hline
    $6 - 8$          & $5$                      & $7$                & $35$                 \\ \hline
    $8 - 10$         & $6$                      & $9$                & $54$                 \\ \hline
    $10 - 12$        & $2$                      & $11$               & $22$                 \\ \hline
    $12 - 14$        & $3$                      & $13$               & $39$                 \\ \hline \rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{4ex}
    Total            & $\sum f_i = 20$          &                    & $\sum f_i x_i = 162$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the causes of your problem are rules added to `\hline` remove them.

if you like to have more vertical space in cells, you can add more space by use of the `makecell` package (or `cellspace`).

**edit:** after considering @Bernard comment in the first case the solution is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            top=0.7in,bottom=0.4in,left=0.7in,right=0.6in,
            headsep=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb}    % loads amsfonts
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\large
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Class   & $(f_i)$   & $(x_i)$  & $f_i \cdot x_i$       \\ \hline
    0--2    & 1         & 1        & 1                     \\ \hline
    2--4    & 2         & 3        & 6                     \\ \hline  
    4--6    & 1         & 5        & 5                     \\ \hline
    6--8    & 5         & 7        & 35                    \\ \hline 
    8--10   & 6         & 9        & 54                    \\ \hline
    10--12  & 2         & 11       & 22                    \\ \hline
    12--14  & 3         & 13       & 39                    \\ \hline
    Total   & $\sum f_i = 20$  &   & $\sum f_i x_i = 162$  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks..for your kind cooperation.

Comment: @Zarko: for numerical ranges, the symbol is not a  `minus` sign, but an `\endash`. Typographically, the spacing is very different. One can use `\textendash`, or the approximation `{-}` to neutralise the spacing.

Comment: @Bernard, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign should be an en-dash.

Instead of adding `$` signs everywhere, it's easier to use `array`.

I also propose an *uncaged* version.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second instance
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{|r@{\mbox{--}}l|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{%
  \rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{4ex}% <--- don't forget
  \text{Class}%
} & (f_i) & (x_i) & f_i \cdot x_i      \\ \hline
0&2   & 1             & 1             & 1                  \\ \hline
2&4   & 2             & 3             & 6                  \\ \hline
4&6   & 1             & 5             & 5                  \\ \hline
6&8   & 5             & 7             & 35                 \\ \hline
8&10  & 6             & 9             & 54                 \\ \hline
10&12 & 2             & 11            & 22                 \\ \hline
12&14 & 3             & 13            & 39                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{%
  \rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{4ex}% <--- don't forget
  \text{Total}%
} & \sum f_i = 20 && \sum f_i x_i = 162 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

\bigskip

$\begin{array}{r@{\mbox{--}}lccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{Class}} & f_i & x_i & f_ix_i \\
\midrule
0&2   & 1             & 1             & 1                  \\
2&4   & 2             & 3             & 6                  \\
4&6   & 1             & 5             & 5                  \\
6&8   & 5             & 7             & 35                 \\
8&10  & 6             & 9             & 54                 \\
10&12 & 2             & 11            & 22                 \\
12&14 & 3             & 13            & 39                 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{Total}} & \sum f_i = 20 && \sum f_i x_i = 162 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great sir.this is an outstanding way. Once again millions and trillions times thanks.